# while export file from html table - non editable / editable fields using jquery/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While exporting  file from HTML table -in that Excel file some are non editable and some are editable fields as default using JQuery/HTML. How to acheive?

Sample example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column One </th>
        <th>Column Two</th>
        <th>Column Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1 Col1</td>
        <td>row1 Col2</td>
        <td>row1 Col3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>row2 Col1</td>
        <td>row2 Col2</td>
        <td>row2 Col3</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row3 Col1</td>
        <td>row3 Col2</td>
        <td>row3 Col3</td>  
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<script>
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {     
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you saying you want the excel file to make some of the fields read-only? If so, it's impossible the way you are doing it - you aren't creating an Excel file (.xlsx) which would be able to understand those kinds of rules, you're just creating a text file containing HTML in a format that Excel can read. And you can't create a .xlsx using javascript/jQuery. You'd have to take the raw data from the server-side (assuming you have access to it) and use some sort of server-side plugin to create the file.

Comment: Thanks. Any other UI plugin is there to achieve above requirement?

Comment: I don't know. It's probably not hard to find out though: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20create%20excel%20file